# How to customize(change) the JEditorPane border?

Tags: java, swing, border, jeditorpane

Is there any solution to remove default(bevel) border of JEditorPane?
I have tested the `JEditorPane#setBorder()` method, but it doesn't work, and bevel border is still exist.
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
The code I have tried so far(and it doesn't make any sense).

```
private Border b=new LineBorder(Color.black,1);
void remove_border(JEditorPane com){
com.setBorder(b);
}
```

I want to remove the editor border, not the scroll bar.

Comment: Is the problem the border of the editor pane or the scrollpane? Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: I want to remove the editor border, not the scroll bar. == by default you can to see only Borders from JScrollPane (without using seom of custom LookAndFeels)

Comment: code in your edit talking about nothing, did you read SSCCE

Comment: That is not a SSCCE, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on my machine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class JEditorPaneBorderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jFrame.setContentPane(panel);

        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        new JEditorPaneBorderExample().remove_border(editor);
        panel.add(editor);

        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Border b = new LineBorder(Color.black, 1);

    void remove_border(JEditorPane com) {
        com.setBorder(b);
    }

}
```